Ubuntu 22.04 randomly hangs for ~1-5 seconds
I've been experiencing a frustrating issue with my Ubuntu 22.04 system where it randomly hangs or freezes for about 1 to 5 seconds. This happens intermittently and without any clear pattern, making it difficult to pinpoint the cause. Here are some details about my setup and what I've tried so far:
System Details:
   OS: Ubuntu 22.04 (64-bit)
   Kernel: 5.x.x-generic
   Hardware: [Brief description of your hardware, e.g., CPU, GPU, RAM, storage]
   Desktop Environment: [e.g., GNOME, KDE, etc.]
Symptoms:
The system becomes unresponsive for 1 to 5 seconds.
This happens randomly, regardless of the applications I'm using.
The mouse cursor freezes, and keyboard input is not registered during these hangs.
After the hang, the system resumes normal operation without any error messages.
Steps taken so far:
Checked System Logs: I reviewed /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log but couldn't find any obvious errors or warnings that correspond to the hangs.
Updated System: Ensured all packages and the kernel are up to date using sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.
Checked Disk Health: Ran smartctl to check for disk errors, but everything appears normal.
Monitored System Resources: Used htop and iotop to monitor CPU, memory, and I/O usage, but didn't notice any spikes or abnormalities during the hangs.
Disabled Extensions: Disabled GNOME extensions to see if they were causing the issue, but the hangs persisted.
Checked for Overheating: Monitored system temperatures using sensors, but temperatures were within normal ranges.
Additional Information:
The hangs seem to happen more frequently when I'm using multiple applications, but they also occur when the system is idle.
I'm not running any particularly resource-intensive applications when the hangs occur.
Request:
I'm looking for any advice or suggestions on how to diagnose and resolve this issue. Has anyone else experienced similar hangs on Ubuntu 22.04? What other steps can I take to troubleshoot this problem? Are there any specific logs or tools that might help identify the cause of these random hangs?

Totally unreadable that is the single longest sentence I have ever seen. You might consider editing it and make it something that can be read.

I experienced the same problem. I don't have the details handy, but it's something like 5.13-latest causes journalctl -b -f to show that my CPU is stalled for very many seconds, and top shows some btrfs-cache-worker using 100% CPU on 2 CPUs. For now, I'm booting the older 5.8-something kernel and that's working fine.
